# Can't assign an array to the global variable "name"

Tags: javascript, arrays

This has been incredibly frustrating, especially given the simplicity of it.  Simple javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var name = new Array("cat","dog");

document.write(name[1]);

</script>
```

This script prints: "a"  (as in the "a" from "cat"...aka name[0][1]...).

Yet when I change it to document.write(name), it prints the whole array (i.e. "cat,dog").  Why for the love of god is this simple array failing to print the entire string (which should be "dog")?!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nPMYm/ What browser are you using?

Comment: Twas using Chrome, but Rob nailed it down below. Cursed pre-named variables!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global variable `name` refers to the existing [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property, which was used to set the name of the browser window. It converts any value assigned to it to a string:

```js
window.name = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(typeof window.name, window.name);
```

If you change the variable name to e.g. `names` it will do as expected.

Using `name` in function scope scope will work fine of course.

Comment: Is this only in certain browsers? It works fine in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/nPMYm/1/ *edit:* seems to fail in Chrome.

Comment: Oh dear god. He's absolutely right. Well done, Rob! You have earned yourself some delicious brownie points. Don't use them all in one place! Thanks!

Comment: @the_red_baron: Another solution is to wrap your code in an immediate function `(function(){ /* your code here */}());`. Then the variables are local to that function.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I'm trying it in Chrome.  In firefox it doesn't do this unless you actually assign it to window.name.

Comment: @FelixKling: thanks for the alternative solution, I'll check it out.

Comment: Interesting... but if I create a normal var, `var name`, and later do `alert(window.name)`, it shows me the array. So it seems that Firefox allows to overwrite this property when declaring global variables.

Comment: This is the right answer, however shouldn't the moral of the story be "use closures" rather than "try to remember not to call your vars any of a group of keywords"?

Comment: @funkybro well to be pedantic, you still have to avoid keywords, closures or not, but closures can certainly help regarding global variables. :)

Answer (score -2):

You should use this instead:

```
var name = ["cat", "dog"];
document.write(name[1]);
```

Comment: True, as long as he doesn't assign anything to a variable called 'Array' anywhere.