# javascript split() not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have the simple function below:

```
    function inName(){
        name = bio.name.split(" ");
        return name[0];
    }
```

Where 'bio.name' is a string such as "Bill Gates".  It is returning the 'B' as index 0 rather than splitting on the white space and returning 'Bill' as index 0 of the array.

Comment: You're wrong, it works as expected.

Comment: Can you create a simple example? I imagine you will discover the problem in doing so..

Comment: I think you should probably change your structure up a bit. It is hard to tell why without seeing the data you are passing to it. 2-things I would suggest: 1- look at a regex... 2- change your function to `function inName(nameParam)`  and then when you call the function call `inName(bio.name)` and in your function call `name = nameParam.split(" ");` and so now you can be positive of the value you are passing to the function.

Comment: Solved.  Saved bio.name into var name, then split.

Comment: `"Bill Gates".split(" ")[0] === "Bill"`

Comment: Ah, of course. The problem is that `window.name` has a setter which stringifies the global variable. Sorry (now deleted) answer for the downvote, it really fixed the problem. This question is a duplicate, but I can't find it now.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding why it initially was splitting letters individually, and how saving the var first, then splitting with another var works.  It is part of a class I am in.

Comment: @MickeyR if you did `var name` _inside_ your function, then the variable is local to that function (and not `window.name` which exhibits the problem.)

Comment: Duplicate: [Can't assign an array to the global variable "name"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7865023/1529630)